# fetch data from mysql and make a predicate in prolog

Tags: mysql, prolog

I have a table in mysql that includes 3 columns

**table**

id

name

age

I want to take the age value and make a rule in prolog that can find if this guy is child or adult or an 
elderly
SO i want to have something like:

```
elderly(age):- age>60.

child(age):- age<12.

young(age):- age>12 and age<18.

adult(age):- age>18 and age<60.
```

Can anyone tell me how i can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, variables in Prolog must be capitalized:

```
elderly(Age) :- Age > 60.
child(Age) :- Age < 12.
young(Age) :- Age > 12, Age < 18.
adult(Age) :- Age > 18, Age < 60.
```

Now connecting to the database will vary depending on your implementation. Odds are good you're using SWI, so the connection process is [described in the documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%28%27packages/odbc.html%27%29) but will look something like this:

```
odbc_connect(mydb, [user(u), password(p), alias(mydb), open(once)]),
odbc_query(mydb, 'SELECT * FROM people', row(Id,Name,Age)),
elderly(Age), 
write('Found an elderly person: '), writeln(Name).
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: main returns false...I've checked everything and i can't find any mistake.

    connect :- odbc_connect('connect', _,
      [ user(root),
        alias(test1911),
        password(''),
        open(once)
      ]).
    
    disconnect :- odbc_disconnect(test1911).
    
    main :- connect, odbc_query(test1911, 'SELECT * FROM test', row(id,name,age)),elderly(age), 
    write('Found an elderly person: '), writeln(name).
    
    
    elderly(age) :- age > 60.
    child(age) :- age < 12.
    young(age) :- age > 12, age < 18.
    adult(age) :- age > 18, age < 60.